# How do I rewrite committer names in a git repository?

Tags: git

I converted a Subversion repository to Git using git svn but unfortunately only now noticed that some of the author information was wrong. The converted repository is not shared with anybody yet, so I'd like to rewrite the commit logs in it - if possible.

How can I rewrite a git repository so that the log for all his commits show e.g.

```
Author: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
```

instead of

```
Author: John Do <john.do@example.com>
```

I tried to do this myself, and it seems that [git-filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) is what I need. I didn't manage to make it do this, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The ProGit book](http://www.git-scm.com/book/) has [an example of doing this](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) that should probably work for you.

```
$ git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "schacon@localhost" ];
    then
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Scott Chacon";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="schacon@example.com";
            git commit-tree "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

Comment: Don't forget `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`.

Comment: this works only on master branch