# Could I change my name and surname in all previous commits?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I would like to change my name, surname and email in my all commits, is it possible?

Comment: Is it a reprository for only you, for a few people or for a big project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the author of a commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rewrite committer names in a git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566809/how-do-i-rewrite-committer-names-in-a-git-repository)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Use [`git-filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Josh Lee" ];
  then export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Hobo Bob"; export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=hobo@example.com;
  fi; git commit-tree "$@"'
```

This only affects the author, not the committer (which for most commits will be the same as the author). If you want to rewrite those as well, set the `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` variables.

The [standard warning](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) about rewriting history applies; only do it to history that has not yet been shared.

## June 2018 Update

The manual now includes a solution, using `--env-filter`, in its examples: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples :

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
    if test "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "root@localhost"
    then
        GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=john@example.com
    fi
    if test "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "root@localhost"
    then
        GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=john@example.com
    fi
' -- --all
```

Comment: If you’re using `msysgit`, you still have access to `bash`. Otherwise, I’ve no clue.

Comment: @Joshua if you're using something where you don't have bash, you could probably use windows batch scripting, though I haven't tried it.

Comment: and what about tags? this solution won't change author of tags

Comment: @Joshua check out the git repo on a linux box and perform the fix there

Comment: Is there an options which result in new branch and leave source commits intact?

Comment: +1. Good solution.  Would be even nicer if you put the old and new emails in two env var at the beginning of the line,  something like: `OLD_EMAIL=local@localhost && NEW_EMAIL=john@example.com && git filter-branch --env-filter "
if test \"\$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL\" = \"$OLD_EMAIL\"
then
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$NEW_EMAIL
fi

if test \"\$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL\" = \"$OLD_EMAIL\"
then
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$NEW_EMAIL
fi
" -- --all`  then this answer would be workable from command-line

Comment: @EugenKonkov Source commits are intact because you create a branch/tree from the first commit you modify.  If you want a branch to point to old commits, just first create a new branch before rewriting history.

Comment: Wonderful, but don't forget `--tag-name-filter cat` to rewrite tags; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7673115/421049 . Unfortunately the tagger emails don't seem to be updated; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51790056/421049 .

Comment: @xiay Is `root@localhost` supposed to stay the same?

Answer (score 57):

To rewrite both author and commiter in all selected commits:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter \
'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "OldAuthor Name" ]; then \
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Author Name";\
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=authorEmail@example.com;\
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Commmiter Name";\
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=commiterEmail@example.com;\
fi;\
git commit-tree "$@"'
```

Comment: But how to apply changes to remote server?

Comment: @Viky Try `git push --all origin --force`

Comment: It works for me ! I'm using GitLab, I have to Unprotect the  branch before push command.

Answer (score 40):

If there are no other authors, you can do:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="authorname"; \
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=mail@example.com; git commit-tree "$@"'
```

Comment: It's not rewriting "Committer:" info.

Comment: It's not intended to rewrite committer info. If you want to do that, export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL as well (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 13):

Save the script below as e.g. `~/.bin/git-replace-author` and run it using, e.g:

```
git replace-author "John Ssmith" "John Smith" "johnsmith@example.com"
```

With no arguments, it updates all commits with your name to use your current email address according to Git config.

```
DEFAULT_NAME="$(git config user.name)"
DEFAULT_EMAIL="$(git config user.email)"
export OLD_NAME="${1:-$DEFAULT_NAME}"
export NEW_NAME="${2:-$DEFAULT_NAME}"
export NEW_EMAIL="${3:-$DEFAULT_EMAIL}"

echo "Old:" $OLD_NAME "<*>"
echo "New:" "$NEW_NAME <$NEW_EMAIL>"
echo "To undo, use: git reset $(git rev-parse HEAD)"

git filter-branch --env-filter \
'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "${OLD_NAME}" ]; then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="${NEW_NAME}"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="${NEW_EMAIL}"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="${NEW_NAME}"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="${NEW_EMAIL}"
fi'
```

[Raw](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/zaz/384d85a2832dcce5cffc136c2b6cdb4e/raw/6852527aeaa8a2899904370293571388b4680591/git-replace-author) (to download)

Comment: As a short note: `~/.bin/` needs to be inside the users `$PATH` and the file needs to be executable, so run: `chmod +x ~/.bin/git-replace-author`.

Comment: And what it do with arguments?

Answer (score 3):

Only if you haven't pushed your commits to the world. Other wise everyone else has your old name in their repo which is unlikely you can change everyone's.

Comment: True, but in some cases you have no choice. I my case I had a wrong email address configured in my git config (as I could see with "git config --global -l"). As a result, I had no commit activity showing up in my own Github repo (because the email address didn't match with the email configured in Github) ! To solve this, I fixed my local commits using the recipe from http://stackoverflow.com/a/23564785/2474068 (worked perfect) and then I pushed the changed commits to Github using "git push -u -f origin master" (with the force flag "-f"). That goes against accepted practice but I had no choice!

Comment: Yes, my point was that any forks of that repo wouldn't have that change unless they accepted your force push. It would be challenging to get every fork to update :)

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), [**`git filter-branch` (and BFG) is deprecated**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

The equivalent would be, using [**`newren/git-filter-repo`**](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), and its [example section](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES):

```
cd repo
git filter-repo --mailmap my-mailmap
```

with `my-mailmap`:

```
Correct Name <correct@email.com> <old@email.com>
```

That would replace the author name and email of any commit done by anyone with `<old@email.com>`

See [`git shortlog` mapping author section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors) for the exact syntax of