# Sourcetree and github

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

When I push commits to github repo from windows github client, I can see my github username and link to my profile in history, like this:

> initial commit [[username](https://github.com/username)]

But when I push changes from SourceTree, in commits history it looks like:

> initial commit [mac_username]

I want my history on github.com looks like the first example (with github username and link to the profile) What settings I should enable in SourceTree to get it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the config in those repos:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Make sure the repo on Mac has the same settings than the one on Windows.

[This thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/49996/how-to-change-username) details how to change those settings in SourceTree, but check if "Allow SourceTree to modify your global Git configuration file" is set: that means it would apply to *all* your local git repo (Github or not).

[image: settings]

The "Full name" is a bit misleading, in that you should use your GitHub login name (and GitHub account email), in order to generate the right commit author history on GitHub.

Comment: Is it possible to change the commits that I have made till now to the new username? I did what you say, and now the commits are showing up on GitHub, but all my older commits are not showing up. Is there some workaround so that I can see all my activities in the "Your Contributions" pane?

Comment: @aksh1t yes, using filter-branch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/870367/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7221132/6309 (to manage the push --force)

Answer (score 2):

Go to preferences and on General tab you can see two text fields, one for Full Name and other for email, set the name whatever you want to appear