# Github Dual Authorship one Developer

Tags: android, git, github, intellij-idea

I have been working on a Android project in IntelliJ and I never really figured out how to setup Git properly, so I have it so I can make commits, but then I have to do something weird which is go to Eclipse and have them actually pushed to GitHub. (I believe it is because the project was created in advance on GitHub and for some reason I can't get an existing project to link up properly but if someone knows how that would be great to know) Anyways, my issue is that on my computer I have didn't realize I had been authoring my commits under a different name, and so on GitHub they are not linked to my GitHub username. Is there a way to merge the two authors or something to fix this issue?

Comment: Okay I just decided to use Git Gui to handle the IntelliJ problem - but is there a way I can go back and fix all the other misassigned user names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the answer I was looking for on this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493936/git-could-i-change-my-name-and-surname-in-all-previous-commits). I wasn't looking for the correct thing earlier but basically just did what was advised, you will have to do a

> git push --force

though.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter 'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" == "Josh Lee" ];
  then export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Hobo Bob"; export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=hobo@example.com;
  fi; git commit-tree "$@"'
```