# Why users can see the domain passwords in TFS git repo "pull requests" history?

Tags: git, tfs

We use Git repository in TFS in our organization. Recently it has been noticed that users can see other users domain passwords in a "pull requests" history.

When I go to the Git repository in TFS web access -> <kbd>Pull requests</kbd> -> <kbd>Completed</kbd> and open it - in the "Commits" tab I can see an entry such as

```
36214
c133bb by danyl < USER's AD PASSWORD HERE >, 6 hours ago
```

What is it, TFS bug or configuration error?

We are using AD integration for TFS. All Git users are Active Directory users

TFS version: 14.95.25122.0 (Tfs2015.Update2)

Comment: What is the setting of that user's `user.email` configuration setting?  You can run `git config user.email` to see it.  I'll wager a decent hunk of money that they've put their password where their email should go.

Comment: But we are using AD integration for TFS. All Git users are Active Directory users

Comment: What they enter in their Git user settings will be registered as the Comitter and Athor. TFS will store the AD credentials as Committer.

Comment: If  @EdwardThomson is right, then this post will help you clean up your archive. It will require force-push though. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23564785/736079 It depends on Bash shell.

Comment: @VitalyLyashenko It doesn't matter if they're AD users or not.  Users are prompted to enter their email address, and that user likely fat-fingered and entered their password out of habit.  Understandable, and has nothing to do with AD or anything else.  Run `git config user.email` and see what it says.

Comment: @EdwardThomson,  @ jessehouwing Thanks. Several users made the same misconfiguration