# Is there a faster way to update all the commits Author in the **master** branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I need to over-write/update Author in my entire master branch git repo.

I know I can do this one by one

`git commit --amend --author="John Doe <jdoe@outlook.com>" --no-edit
git push -f`

but that will take me weeks.

Is there a faster way to update all the commits Author in the **master** branch?

Comment: There's a *less fast* way to do it (see filter-branch), in a way, since the proposed way (through --amend) is not only time-consuming, it won't work.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried.

Comment: [Could I change my name and surname in all previous commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493936/could-i-change-my-name-and-surname-in-all-previous-commits)

Comment: The purpose of `git filter-branch` is to apply an operation to each commit in a given branch.

Answer (score -4):

You can write a shell script to for-in all the commits and push them back, like.

```
for commits in $(git log --pretty=format:"%h")
do
  git commit --amend....
done
```

If that does not work, like others are suggesting it may not, try referring official article, https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info

Comment: No. If you modify a commit, all its children will change. OP's first idea is not workable

Comment: Wow... you're so billiant ... let me try

Comment: @kyo Try it on a clone to measure the damage, yes, then throw it away.